# SQL SUM error, mySQL environment

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Ok, I didn't see my issue addressed within the SQL Sum answer summaries so far, so point me there if I missed something there.
Below, my error is

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(payments.payment) as cust_pmts (SUM(payments.payment)/6) as Jan_cohor' at line 2"

My code seems to match the SQL tutorials I'm using as reference with modification based on tables renamed.  Please advise.  Thanks!

```
SELECT customer.customer_id as cust_id
       SUM(payments.payment) as cust_pmts
       (SUM(payments.payment)/6) as Jan_cohort_clv
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
LEFT JOIN telemon_customer_data customer
ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING customer.account_created_on between "2016-01-01" and "2016-01-31"
```

Comment: you're missing commas after each field in select

Answer (score 0):

add commas to separate your fields in the select

```
 SELECT customer.customer_id as cust_id,
       SUM(payments.payment) as cust_pmts,
       (SUM(payments.payment)/6) as Jan_cohort_clv
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
LEFT JOIN telemon_customer_data customer
ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
where  customer.account_created_on between "2016-01-01" and "2016-01-31"
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```

Also I believe you want to group by customer_id, and that you having clause must be in where

Answer (score 0):

Missing commas, and your `having` should probably be a `where`, and your `group by` should use the column name, not the ordinal from the `select`.

If you only want `customer.account_created_on` for a certain date range, why use a `left join` instead of an `inner join`? Or did you want all customers even if they do not have `payments`?

```
SELECT 
    customer.customer_id as cust_id
  , SUM(payments.payment) as cust_pmts
  , (SUM(payments.payment)/6) as Jan_cohort_clv
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
  inner JOIN telemon_customer_data customer
    ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
where customer.account_created_on between "2016-01-01" and "2016-01-31"
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```

all customers in the given date range even if they do not have `payments`:

```
SELECT 
    customer.customer_id as cust_id
  , SUM(payments.payment) as cust_pmts
  , (SUM(payments.payment)/6) as Jan_cohort_clv
FROM telemon_customer_data customer
  left JOIN telemon_payments_data payments
    ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
where customer.account_created_on between "2016-01-01" and "2016-01-31"
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```

Comment: Going to have to re-review the HAVING and WHERE descriptions.

Comment: I would prefer to know all customers even if they don't have payments, although that didn't occur to me before your comment!  thanks.  Looks like I have to re-review INNER and LEFT JOIN too.

Comment: @herbacidal I like the visual illustrations for joins here: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php